# ASP.NET MVC 3 RC AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas() and dynamically loaded assemblies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am currently experimenting with dynamically loaded areas with ASP.NET MVC 3 RC. I've seen it written in many places that this is not what areas are intended for, and (at least pre-MVC 2) not possible, say [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/12/30/asp-net-mvc-2-and-why-dynamic-area-is-not-supported.aspx) for example.

But still! It should be possible to get it to work, right? I've created a solution, added a MVC 3 project, added an area and some content. All is working well. Now I created a new class library project (in the same solution), added a reference to it from the MVC-project, and started moving over the area-related parts to the library. Changed the output-directory of the library project to the area-folder of the MVC-project, and made sure the Views and their web.config are copied to the output-folder.

After reading so much about how you couldn't have external areas, it was a little surprising that this worked. No problem at all really! The problem starts when I remove the reference between the projects, and instead load the library in code. (Before calling `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()`.) Now it doesn't work. At all.

I've been poking around a bit in the source for MVC 3, and the problem seems to be with [`BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.getreferencedassemblies.aspx) which is used to get the assemblies to look for implementations of `AreaRegistration`.

Now, I'm not 100% sure about this, but it seems as if this method only looks at assemblies that were present/referenced at compile-time, can someone confirm if this is in fact so?

I have debugged through this, and that method-call does indeed not find the assembly I loaded just before the call to it. It might be because of something else that I've missed perhaps.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The way things work is a bit complicated.

`GetReferencedAssemblies` includes referenced assemblies, not loaded assemblies. This includes:

- all assemblies referenced in you application's web.config (such as `System.Web.Mvc`)
- everything inherited from root web.config, which includes things like `System`, `System.Web` and others that you do not have to add yourself. (You can take a look at the list here: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\web.config`). 
   **It also contains a special `*` item, which**:
- includes everything in your site's `bin` folder

So now take your app v1 (everything in a single app). Everything works because the application code gets compiled into the bin folder which gets automatically included. Also, all of the area views etc are in the application itself so they are accessible.

Now in app v2 (different project with a proj-to-proj reference **and** a custom build task that copies the views to the right location in your main app) everything still works, because by default a proj-to-proj references means that the class library binary gets copied to your app's bin folder. So by the above rules, the area code still gets loaded correctly. The fact that you've set the library's output path to be some location within your main app's Areas folder does not actually make a difference - you just end up with two copies of the binary.

Now in app v3 (no proj-proj ref, area library assembly loaded manually) your library assembly gets loaded too late. By the time your code runs the set of referenced assemblies has already been locked and can no longer be changed.

There is a way to run code and add items to the list of registered assemblies: you can do it using the [`AddReferencedAssembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.addreferencedassembly.aspx) method which *must* be invoked from a [`PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute` method](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/16/three-hidden-extensibility-gems-in-asp-net-4.aspx).

Of course you still have to deal with how you manage your view files. The way you currently have it set up is pretty much the same as having the views in the main application (since they effectively get copied into the right location).

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks a mil!

Yes I know that at the moment it is basically the same as having just one project, but I wanted to separate them slowly and see where I hit problems as I went, instead of all problems at once :)

I'm considering maybe compiling in the views as resources in the assembly and do my own virtual path/file implementations, unless that would be too much of a performance issue.. As I said, just playing around at the moment to see what's possible and what's not!

Thanks again!

Comment: You might like to look at marking all the views in your area assembly as embedded resources and look at implementing a virtual path provider. That's what I did to achieve drag'n drop area assemblies that I could just place in the bin directory of the main site.

Comment: @Joshua Hayes - can you send me your pluggable areas solution?

Comment: @JoshuaHayes - I am also interested in seeing your drag'n drop solution.  Would you care to share?  I've been looking for a solution to this problem and this would help greatly!

Answer (score 6):

1 - Seperate you Mvc Areas into differrent Mvc Projects to be compiled into their own seperate assemblies

2 - Add this to your AssemblyInfo.cs class, to call a method when the application is loaded

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(PluginAreaBootstrapper), "Init")]
```

3 - Here's what the Init method looks like when it's invoked during the load

```cs
public class PluginAreaBootstrapper
{
    public static readonly List<Assembly> PluginAssemblies = new List<Assembly>();

    public static List<string> PluginNames()
    {
        return PluginAssemblies.Select(
            pluginAssembly => pluginAssembly.GetName().Name)
            .ToList();
    }

    public static void Init()
    {
        var fullPluginPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Areas");

        foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(fullPluginPath, "*Plugin*.dll"))
            PluginAssemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFile(file));

        PluginAssemblies.ForEach(BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly);
    }
}
```

4 - Add a custom RazorViewEngine

```cs
public class PluginRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public PluginRazorViewEngine()
    {
        AreaMasterLocationFormats = new[]
        {
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
        };

        AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = new[]
        {
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
        };

        var areaViewAndPartialViewLocationFormats = new List<string>
        {
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
        };

        var partialViewLocationFormats = new List<string>
        {
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
        };

        var masterLocationFormats = new List<string>
        {
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
        };

        foreach (var plugin in PluginAreaBootstrapper.PluginNames())
        {
            masterLocationFormats.Add(
                "~/Areas/" + plugin + "/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml");
            masterLocationFormats.Add(
                "~/Areas/" + plugin + "/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml");
            masterLocationFormats.Add(
                "~/Areas/" + plugin + "/Views/Shared/{1}/{0}.cshtml");
            masterLocationFormats.Add(
                "~/Areas/" + plugin + "/Views/Shared/{1}/{0}.vbhtml");

            partialViewLocationFormats.Add(
                "~/Areas/" + plugin + "/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml");
            partialViewLocationFormats.Add(
                "~/Areas/" + plugin + "/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml");
            partialViewLocationFormats.Add(
                "~/Areas/" + plugin + "/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml");
            partialViewLocationFormats.Add(
                "~/Areas/" + plugin + "/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml");

            areaViewAndPartialViewLocationFormats.Add(
                "~/Areas/" + plugin + "/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml");
            areaViewAndPartialViewLocationFormats.Add(
                "~/Areas/" + plugin + "/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml");
            areaViewAndPartialViewLocationFormats.Add(
                "~/Areas/" + plugin + "/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml");
            areaViewAndPartialViewLocationFormats.Add(
                "~/Areas/" + plugin + "/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml");
            areaViewAndPartialViewLocationFormats.Add(
                "~/Areas/" + plugin + "/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml");
            areaViewAndPartialViewLocationFormats.Add(
                "~/Areas/" + plugin + "/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml");
        }

        ViewLocationFormats = partialViewLocationFormats.ToArray();
        MasterLocationFormats = masterLocationFormats.ToArray();
        PartialViewLocationFormats = partialViewLocationFormats.ToArray();
        AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = areaViewAndPartialViewLocationFormats.ToArray();
        AreaViewLocationFormats = areaViewAndPartialViewLocationFormats.ToArray();
    }
}
```

5 - Register your Areas from your different Mvc (Area) Projects

```
namespace MvcApplication8.Web.MyPlugin1
{
    public class MyPlugin1AreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get { return "MyPlugin1"; }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "MyPlugin1_default",
                "MyPlugin1/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new {action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Sourcecode and additional references can can be found here:**http://blog.longle.io/2012/03/29/building-a-composite-mvc3-application-with-pluggable-areas**

Comment: Huh, look at that, very nice! I'm going to have to give that a try at some point, thank you!

Comment: Hi Bryan, glad this helped :)