# ASP.NET MVC 3 RC and custom ViewEngine to allow for externally loaded Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, viewengine

I'm playing around a little with dividing up a MVC-site into several assemblies (ran into some [issues earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241399/asp-net-mvc-3-rc-arearegistration-registerallareas-and-dynamically-loaded-assem)).

Now I have almost everything working, got the main MVC project that loads in any external assemblies it can find. The external assemblies are basically external *areas*. When I had it copy the Views and web.config to the main-sites Areas-folder everything worked just fine. Now, that folder will most likely start to get a little bloated after a while, so I thought I'd try to add in the Views as resources in the area-assembly instead, see how that worked.

Created my own `VirtualPathProvider` and my own `VirtualFile`, registered them with the `HostingEnvironment` thinking all was well. Turns out it only uses the `VirtualPathProvider` added to the `HostingEnvironment` at the first load, not by the following View-loads by the `ViewEngine`.. Ok fine, found a few examples of how you could get around this by implementing your own `ViewEngine` to use your own VPP. But yeah, this doesn't seem to be a workable solution for MVC 3..

As it turns out, neither `RazorViewEngine` nor `WebFormViewEngine` implement two of the "key-functions" it seems, `FileExists` and `IsValidPath`. These are inherited from `BuildManagerViewEngine`, and you know what? These methods are marked as `sealed`..

Anyone who has tried this with MVC 3 and perhaps could nudge me in the right direction? I've been staring at the MVC 3 source now for quite a while but I just can't see any way of doing this..

Comment: And BuildManagerViewEngine is inherited from VirtualPathProviderViewEngine, which actually looks like it uses the HostingEnvirnment's VPP.. Now I'm confused..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I feel a little stupid, it seems I loaded the VPP too late.. Had it in `Application_Start`, but when I moved it to my `PreApplicationStartMethod` instead, it was used by the `ViewEngine`. (So no implementation of `ViewEngine` seems to be needed, wey!)

Problem now is that when I try to get to a View that's stored as a resource, I get to download it instead of having it rendered.. But that's something different from this so!